# Fast alternative to jar command to update a .jar

Tags: java, jar, zip, archive

I need to insert a folder into a .jar file.

So far I tried

> jar u myJar.jar myFolder

However this takes for ever, the folder is +300MB. I also tried with

> zip myJar.jar myFolder

it says

> updating: myFolder/ (stored 0%)

but nothing happens

Anyone knows a good alternative?

Comment: Rather large for a JAR file. Why does that folder have to be inside the JAR?

Comment: the hadoop server does not like the -libjars

Comment: Does the `-r` option to zip helps ? (I don't know if it will be faster but the zip command will do what you want)

Comment: Yes this did the job, it is very fast now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found out in the comments, the `zip` command was missing a `-r` to recursively include the folder :

```
zip -r myJar.jar myFolder
```

Comment: thanks, do you know the option to avoid compression?

Comment: `-0` to `-9` tunes the compression : `-0` for no compression, `-9` for max compression (the default is `-6`).